# How does this code snippet work?

Tags: c, pointers

The code is just very simple, yet I scratch my head at the results.
I am just playing pointer arithmetics and want to print out the array 
but I get the numbers of the array plus 3 more. Where do those 3 extra come from ?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int my_array[] = {1,3,5,6,73,343,34};

int *pointer_numeros;

int main (void) {
int i = 0;  
pointer_numeros = my_array;

while(*pointer_numeros) {

        printf("los numeros del array son %d\t %d\n\n", i++, *pointer_numeros++);

            }

            getchar();
            return 0;

    }
```

Comment: By itself, pointer-based iteration won't work until you insert a stopping element in it. On a similar note, does anyone know how and where dynamic arrays (the sort you allocate using malloc) store their sizes, and why static arrays don't store their sizes?

Comment: @susmits: It's implementation-defined, but you can imagine that `malloc` could store the details immediately before the first element.  Static arrays don't need to store their sizes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*pointer_numeros` does not evaluate to false at the end of the array; it will carry on walking through memory until it hits an address whose contents are zero (but this is *undefined behaviour*).

You can terminate your array in a zero, as others have suggested.  But in general, you will still have a problem: what if some of your elements are themselves zero?

Comment: @retarded: It could be anywhere.  Memory outside the array is generally random garbage (or it could be other variables), so it's largely chance if and when it will find a 0.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to write:

```
int my_array[] = {1,3,5,6,73,343,34,0};
```

?

Your code iterates until it finds a zero in the array.  Your array has no zero in it.

Comment: yes, but I read that C automatically ads a '\0' at the end of the array, or is it only in char arrays ? . Thank you a lot

Comment: Only in strings.  So `char mystr[] = "hello";` will have a zero at the end, but `char mystr[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};` will not.

Comment: perfect, thank you! makes sense. So a lot has been learned by me from this simple thing, both the 0 at the end, why it stopped at a given time, that happened when it came across a memory address containing a zero and that it was only for string arrays that the extra 0 was added.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will only stop when it sees the pointer pointing at 0.  Fix it like this:

```
 int my_array[] = {1,3,5,6,73,343,34,0};
```